# First pin of TXS0102DCUR

Tags: pinout, packages

I bought some TXS0102DCUR, and I am not 100% confident that the first pin is from the side of the stripe (left side, relative to the picture). Could anyone confirm, please? I scanned through the [datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLnurq1N3rAhURMewKHSDHCWAQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Ftxs0102&usg=AOvVaw2jmj-mR44EPIAA2KB1FJWq) but could not find any reference.

[image: TXS0102DCUR]

Comment: The marking indicates that the chip is a TXS0102DCUR in a VSSOP package. And the package image shown in the question matches the one shown in the datasheet at p.30. Pin-1 is the one to the left of the stripe. Another tip: Looking at the chip in a way that you can read the top marking, the bottom-left pin is 1.

Comment: The white bar across the package indicates the pin 1/pin 8 end.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pin 1 is at the (lower) left of your leftmost picture

If that's not completely clear in the data sheet, it's probably because this is effectively a small SMD variation on the traditional idea of DIP packages.

In contrast, beware that with square-pinout packages such as QFP's, the orientation of the label text will often *not* match the orientation in which the chip is symbolically depicted in a data sheet.